# Redirect page based on the referrer in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, referrer

I am looking for a simple solution to redirect visitors who are trying to visit /order/ page from particular referrer to a page /order-2/.

Let's say, visitors are coming from facebook to my homepage, but I don't want facebook visitors to see page /order/, instead I want to redirect them to /order-2/, if that makes sense.

It is wordpress website, so I guess it should be easy to find a solution with a plugin, however I couldn't find anything that would work..

Thanks you for your help!

Comment: So, you want to change the links you offer on your homepage based on what page the user is coming from?

Comment: If that's easier, then yes! I still think that redirecting it to different url when they try to access particular page would be better solution, without changing url's on homepage.

Comment: Ok... Well, then I'll answer it the way you asked it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

This ought to work.  It checks the referrer url for facebook and redirects accordingly.  I'm not 100% certain that wp_safe_redirect will work with a relative url.  This code would go into your functions.php:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_if_facebook');
function redirect_if_facebook(){
    if ( is_page('order') && coming_from_facebook(wp_get_referer()) ){
         wp_safe_redirect( "/order-2/" );
         exit;
     } else{
          wp_safe_redirect( get_home_url() );
          exit;
     }
}

function coming_from_facebook($url_string){
   if ($url_string){
      $url = parse_url($url_string);
      return strpos($url['host'], 'facebook.com');
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! However, will that work when visitors from facebook will try to reach only /order/ page, or it's global redirection to a single page?

Comment: Ok.  I added a check for page.

Comment: hey @vlasits I couldn't get that code to work. Do you know any other ways to do that? thanks

Comment: I don't know of any other ways to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish, but this method should work.  What have you done to try to debug it?  I'd recommend dropping some var_dumps in at various points in the code to see if it is getting run.